# Searching SQL database and CONCAT data

Tags: mysql, join

New to php and sql so i will try to explain:

I have a SEARCH field in PHP and i am trying to search by 'ProposalName' that match with what the user enters.

This prints out fine:

```
SELECT
    rec_proposal.ProposalID,
    ProposalName,
    Status,
    researcher.FirstName,
    researcher.LastName,
    reviewer.FirstName as revFirstName,
    reviewer.LastName as revLastName,
    reviewer.UserID as revUserID,
    review.ReviewDate as revDate, 
    rec_proposal.DateSubmitted
FROM rec_proposal
INNER JOIN User AS researcher
    ON rec_proposal.userid = researcher.UserID
LEFT JOIN review
    ON rec_proposal.ProposalID=review.ProposalID
LEFT JOIN User as reviewer
    ON review.UserID=reviewer.UserID
```

But now using all the columns I need the above code to do something like this

```
  SELECT * FROM rec_proposal WHERE CONCAT (ProposalName) LIKE'%test%'
```

SO if user enters the word 'test' you would see ProposalName that contains the         words test

Comment: you only need to add where condition at the select statement

Comment: don't use BOLD and UPPERCASE is like to scream in web

Comment: why you concat a single column  .. concat fo con concatenate more thena value ..

Comment: Just need an example on what i should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add your `WHERE` clause, it should work. And as scaisEdge noted in their comment, you don't need `CONCAT()` if you are just evaluating a single column :

```
SELECT
    rec_proposal.ProposalID,
    ProposalName,
    Status,
    researcher.FirstName,
    researcher.LastName,
    reviewer.FirstName as revFirstName,
    reviewer.LastName as revLastName,
    reviewer.UserID as revUserID,
    review.ReviewDate as revDate, 
    rec_proposal.DateSubmitted
FROM rec_proposal
INNER JOIN User AS researcher
    ON rec_proposal.userid = researcher.UserID
LEFT JOIN review
    ON rec_proposal.ProposalID=review.ProposalID
LEFT JOIN User as reviewer
    ON review.UserID=reviewer.UserID
WHERE rec_proposal.ProposalName LIKE '%test%'
```

Comment: No probs. [Please mark this answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you.